# How to add a feature to Vim if it's not compiled with that feature?

Tags: vim, cygwin

I am trying to use [clewn](http://clewn.sourceforge.net/) (full gdb support in the vim editor), but the vim I have on my box doesn't have the `netbeans_intg` feature enabled. Is it possible to enable it without recompiling vim?

I am using Cygwin.

**EDIT**: I did fix it by recompiling vim, but I was wondering if there were an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. vim doesn't support compiled-code plugins, and as you've discovered, vim script plugins can depend on compiled-in features which you may not have.